# How to check if hash cookie value is set?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

Normally I have:

```
cookies[:location] = { :value => { :city => 'foo', :country => 'bar' } }
```

However, sometimes `:country` is not set. When I do:

```
cookies[:location][:country].present?
```

to check if country has been set, it returns an error:

```
[:country] is not a symbol
```

How would I check to see if a country is set in `cookie[:location]` if I cannot do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `cookies` hash is nested differently than you are expecting: `:value` is nested under `:location`, `:city` and  `:country` are nested under `:value`. Here is some [irb](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) output to get you started:

```
[~]$ irb
>> cookies={}
=> {}
>> cookies[:location] = { :value => { :city => 'foo', :country => 'bar' } }
=> {:value=>{:city=>"foo", :country=>"bar"}}
>> cookies[:location][:value][:country]
=> "bar"
>> cookies.to_s
=> "{:location=>{:value=>{:city=>\"foo\", :country=>\"bar\"}}}"
```

If you nest the hash like below, you will get your expected behavior:

```
>> cookies[:location] = { :city => 'foo', :country => 'bar' } 
=> {:city=>"foo", :country=>"bar"}
>> cookies[:location][:country]
=> "bar"
```

Comment: Yes, but I think Rails does some kind of auto serialization with cookies. In Rails 3 (3.1 RC4), you can't just do: `cookies[:location] = { :city => 'foo', :country => 'bar' }` and expect to do `cookies[:location][:city]`. You would get an error `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!`. In console (irb), your example works. But not with Rails (Try it out!). Unless I am doing something wrong somewhere

Comment: I have decided to store cookie values in a non-hash form instead. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Sorry for not get back to you sooner. I did take a look at Rails' `cookies` hash and I see what you're saying. Don't have an answer/explanation though. Good luck with your project.